# Embedding a non-static Google API in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: google-maps, ms-access, iframe, google-maps-api-3, ms-access-2010

I am updating an existing access database (2010) that previously used the google maps API embed property within a web browser control. Google has made extensive changes to their google maps API and now my web browser control states: "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe." when in form view.

I attempted to rewrite the URL using the currently available information at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/ but obviously I was not able to incorporate the iframe so this was unsuccessful. Has anyone been successful in updating their embedded google map? I realize there is a static map API option but this not an ideal route because the locations are remote and often the static map does not provide enough contextual details to locate the site...

Here is a similar question I found that is slightly different:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578043/google-maps-embedded-inside-access-2010-not-working-anymore

This is an example of the HTML code necessary:

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.5462165%2C%20-120.97809879&key=AIzaSyD-xIQM90lAFV1QKZoHUaOHRlBXAI8e9WA"></iframe>"
```

Anyone in the community that could help, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Andrew

Comment: You are using Access 2010, which means you can use a webbrowser control. Have you considered simply navigating to the appropriate location?

Comment: Remou, could you explain further? I have tried just using the google maps website but it had too many borders and side bars, it looks sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough, somewhat messy sketch that might work for you. It relies on writing the html out to a file and using that in the webbrowser control.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    strOutput = "<html><body><iframe width=""600"" height=""450"" frameborder=""0"" style=""border:0""" _
      & "src=""https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=40.5462165%2C%20-120.97809879&key=AIzaSyD-xIQM90lAFV1QKZoHUaOHRlBXAI8e9WA""></iframe></body></html>"
    strFile = WriteHTML(strOutput)
    Set wb = Me.wbOutput.Object
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until Not wb.Busy
    wb.Silent = True
    wb.Navigate "file://" & Replace(strFile, "\", "/")
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until Not wb.Busy

End Sub

Function WriteHTML(strHTML) As String
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim strPath As String
Dim fs As Object
Dim ts As Object

    strPath = "z:\docs"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(strPath & "\map.html")
    ts.WriteLine strHTML
    ts.Close

    WriteHTML = strPath & "\map.html"

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Remou! it is going to take me a bit to work through this but from my first glance it looks like a good approach.

Comment: Did this work for you? If not, did you come up with a better solution?